Trying to animate cutting hair particles as if animating a haircut
I am trying to animate a haircut using hair particles with hair dynamics over a human head model.
I can make objects cut the hair particles using dynamic canvas and brushes, but I only seem to be able to make the paint source of the dynamic brush work with proximity.
This limits the way objects cut the particles.  No matter what distance or alpha value I set, the hair particles are cut the same length over the head that the brush object runs through.
I however want the hair particles to only be cut where my dynamic brush object moves through.  So some hair particles should be shorter than others based on the head surface being oval, i.e. I want to simulate a flat top style, but can't cut straight across.  It always cuts the particles to the same length over the surface.
If anyone has a moment to load my test project here I would be very grateful please.
Hair cutting test
If you can figure out for example, how to make the object named 'Plane 002' slide through the hair particles as currently keyframed and only cut the hair particles where the plane passes through.  Ideally I would use Mesh Volume on the dynamic brush to set the cut, but I cannot make this setting work sadly.
Any tips to allow an object to cut particle hair length at exactly where the brush object passes through please?
